# Git How to undo recent merge commit then change to rebase

Tags: git

The commit history looks like this on remote and local:

[image]

I made a mistake so that 'b' and 'c' are merged to the 'merge' point. What I really want to do is creating history like a - b - c. I know I should use rebase instead of merge, and now I have pushed the merged result to the server. I want to know how to modified the history on the remote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new branch `rebase_instead_of_merge` with history as you want it:

```sh
git checkout <commit_hash_for_b>  # checkout the last commit of branch 1
git branch rebase_instead_of_merge
git cherry-pick <commit_hash_for_c>  # cherry-pick all commits of branch 2
```

Overwrite the remote branch `origin/some-feature` to point to the same commits as your new branch `rebase_instead_of_merge`. Before doing this, verify that overwriting history on the remote won’t cause syncing problems for anyone else.

```sh
git push --force origin rebase_instead_of_merge:some-feature
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably *not* modify the history on the remote, especially if someone besides yourself is using this branch.  The reason is that if you rewrite history, you can cause havoc for others when they go to sync up.  If you wanted the linear `a - b - c` history, then here is what you should have done:

```
remote: -- a -- b
            \
local:       c
```

You may rebase the local branch on the remote:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
```

This would leave us with the following:

```
remote: -- a -- b
                 \
local:            c'
```

Then, you could just fast-forward push the local branch to the remote:

```
git push origin master
```

This would result in the remote branch having that linear history.

If you can't tolerate rewriting the history of the remote branch, then you are still left with some options.  You could *revert* the merge commit, and then make more commits on top of that.  But, the merge would still be part of the history of the remote branch.  It might not make sense to even try doing this.